# Actionscript To C#(UNITY)

Tags: c#, android, actionscript-3, unity-game-engine

Can someone please help me translate this actionscript code to c# code

```
public function SetRoadmap( strData : Array ) : void
{
    var arrPart : Array = strData;  //An array of histogram values
    var arrTmp1 : Array = [];

    intTmp_Ori = int(arrPart[0]);
    intTmp = int(intTmp_Ori/100);

    if ( int(int(arrPart[i])/100) == 3 )//Tie
    {
        bNextMove = false;
    }
}
```

Here's my attempt

```
public void SetRoadMap(string strData){
    string arrPart = strData;
    string[] arrTmp1 = new string[]{};

    int intTmp_Ori = arrPart[0];
    int intTmp = intTmp_Ori/100;

    if(//this line is i don't know){

    }
}
```

Could someone please help me out figure out this please. Thank you in advance guys. I need to convert this to c# because it has the same scoreboard rules that i am making in unity.

Comment: You should provide your attempt at translating it if you don't want your question to be rapidly downvoted. I won't downvote you, but it's what I've observed on similar questions.

Comment: okay i'll edit on my attempt

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Also, where does `i` come from?

Comment: What does the existing code do?

Comment: I don't have any issue at all on the code . All i want is to translate it from actionscript to c#

Comment: @PatrickHofman what i does sir is something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bM0NTv8ZWL0 . It is a scoreboard i am making which is called in bacarrat game "small road"

Comment: I nominated this question for reopening because it was edited to include code.  IMO that's enough to address the "debugging help" close reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems this is the translation. As you can see there are some variables undefined, possibly they are class members.

```
public void SetRoadmap(string[] strData)
{
    string[] arrPart = strData;  //An array of histogram values
    string[] arrTmp1 = { };

    int intTmp_Ori = Convert.ToInt32(arrPart[0]);
    int intTmp = intTmp_Ori / 100;

    if (Convert.ToInt32(arrPart[i]) / 100 == 3)//Tie
    {
        bNextMove = false;
    }
}
```

The problem statement containing `int(int())` seems to be a conversion operation. That is necessary since the input is an array of strings. There are several ways to do such conversion, for example to provide integers instead of strings when you can. This code however would do.

Comment: is this how to declare a null string `string[] strData = {}` or this `string[] strData = new string[]{};`

Comment: Please don't "sir" me. And that variable isn't used, so it is useless to do this. If you need to add items later on, you could use a `List<string>`.

Comment: If you mean you want us to convert the entire file you posted, I am sorry, but that is not the intention of Stack Overflow. With the pointers I gave you in my post, you should be able to figure out most yourself. Then ask very specific questions here to resolve parts you don't understand.

Answer (score 3):

I don't quite know what your doing here and I'm making some assumptions. Maybe try to explain in you question what you expect each line to do? As there are variables not doing anything etc.

```
public void SetRoadMap(string[] strData){
    string[] arrPart = strData;
    string[] arrTmp1;

    int intTmp_Ori = Convert.ToInt32(arrPart[0]);
    int intTmp = intTemp_ori/100;

    for(int i = 0; i < arrPart.Length; i++){
        if(Convert.ToInt32(arrPart[i])/100 == 3){
            bNextMove = false;
        }
    }
}
```